# Activity Monitor showing less Physical Memory than actually installed

Tags: memory, apple-silicon, activity-monitor

for some reason on my new M1 Max Mac Studio, Activity Monitor is showing 16 GB of Physical Memory when there is in fact, 64 GB installed.  The other places I've checked (About This Mac, System Report, htop) all correctly show 64 GB of RAM.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and if it is problematic?

[image: Wrong installed RAM in Act. Monitor]

Comment: I presume you've restarted to check it's not a 'one-off'? You could try running diagnostics. I'd be tempted to assume it's a software glitch in Activity Monitor, in the absence of any other corroborating evidence. You could also try to use more than 16Gb with various tasks, and see what Activity Monitor shows then. Ultimately, given it's a brand new (and expensive) machine with integrated RAM, you could take it to an Apple Store for confirmation.

Comment: Reboot. If still the same, talk to Apple.

Comment: I ran the diagnostic and got no issues found.  The weird thing is when I stress test it by running a bunch of processes, the box at the bottom of Activity monitor still seems to show values that are roughly 1/4 of what they should actually read.  For example it shows I'm using 31.2 GB of memory in htop, but the Activity Monitor's Memory Used is only 7.75GB.  The memory values on the list seem to be correct though, Parallels for example is listed as 15.92 GB in Activity monitor's Real Memory, and 16.0G in htop's Resident Memory

Comment: For peace of mind, I'd take it in to an Apple Store. They should be able to diagnose any problem there and then. You don't want to get 3 years down the line and find out there's a fault.